# How to register an AWS ECR image with ansible in an ecs_taskdefinition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ecs

I want to create a `ecs_taskdefinition` with `ansible` based on an imgae that is registered in the `aws-ecr` service as the following:

```
- name: Create task definition
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    family: my_family
    containers:
    - name: my_name
      essential: true
      image: "XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-central-1.amazonaws.com/image_name"
      portMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort:      80
      cpu: 512
      memory: 1024
    state: present
```

However, it returns the following error:

> An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the
>   RegisterTaskDefinition operation: Fargate requires task definition to
>   have execution role ARN to support ECR images.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @Kyu96 posted by solution below

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an IAM role for the fargate to the ECR, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html).

> You can specify an IAM role for your task with the `taskRoleArn` parameter. When you specify an IAM role for a task, its containers can then use the latest versions of the AWS CLI or SDKs to make API requests to the AWS services that are specified in the IAM policy associated with the role. For more information, see [IAM Roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) in the *Amazon Elastic Container Service Developer Guide*.

Comment: and how to include that into the ansible script?

Comment: I'd be interested in that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in order to add the **task_role_arn** and **execution_role_arn**:

```
- name: Create task definition
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    family: my_family
    execution_role_arn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
    task_role_arn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
    containers:
    - name: my_name
      essential: true
      image: "XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-central-1.amazonaws.com/image_name"
      portMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort:      80
      cpu: 512
      memory: 1024
    state: present
```

The role you have to create in advance as described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html

Comment: I tried to replicate this. First Creating an ECS cluster. Creating the task definition as you showed and then a service which uses the task definition and the cluster to (theoretically) run the docker image. The Ansible script finishes without errors, however the container is not running. In the service events I see: `service testservice was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container Instances were found in your cluster. `. 
Any idea what could have went wrong?

Comment: @Kyu96 : after the task you need to run  a service with ecs_service. I used launch_type: 'FARGATE'

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Ansible script for that? I am trying to do the same thing and I keep running into problems: https://pastebin.com/j2ej9DiK

Comment: @Kyu96 the only difference I see is that i am using the taskDefinitionArn and not a string. Therefore, add register: my_task_definition to the task and use: task_definition: "{{ my_task_definition.taskdefinition.taskDefinitionArn }}"

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this right. When trying to register it: https://pastebin.com/RcrhbjqW it fails because no network configuration is provided: https://i.imgur.com/4CwFsYJ.png
Do I really have to create all the security groups etc manually beforehand? :/

Comment: @Kyu96 I created the VPC, security groups with the ansible script before hand.